# Htaccess 404 redirect not working, it doesnt redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

Whit this code, the 404 redirect doesnt work. I dont get any error. If i type in an url that doesnt exists, i only get an empty white page.

**Code updated:**

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ htaccess.php?q=$1 [QSA]  
</IfModule>  


<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>


#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
#RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 404.php/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 http://yourdomain.com/404.php/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/to/404.php [L]
```

The Rewrite rules map that URL to your 404.php script.

See this link for more information: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument

Comment: And if i have a 404.php file, how should i write that into this, and where?

Comment: @Parkolo11 I used index.php because that is what you used in your question. I changed my answer to redirect to a 404.php script. You have to change `/path/to/404.php` with your actual path to that file.

Comment: I updated the post with my new code, but it still doesnt work. I type in an url, that doesnt exsists, and i only get an empty white page, without any redirect.

Comment: Change `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php [L]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.php [L]` (are you sure that is the correct path to that file?) and change `ErrorDocument 404 404.php/` to `ErrorDocument 404 http://yourdomain.com/404.php/`. Please pay attention that you copy my code correctly.

Comment: How does your 404.php script look? The redirection might work and the 404 script is just a white blank page.

Comment: No, there is content on that page.

Comment: I make the changes you say, but still the same problem. If i call the 404 page, to check it, with domain.com/404.php, thats works, so the file is on the server and it works. Its a copy of my about.php file, there are only content on it, nothing else.